# Change Powerlevel9k segment based on current folder

Tags: customization, zsh

I'm trying to customize my zsh terminal, got most things the way I wanted, but then I ran into a page showing how to make language segments to show Javascript, Python, etc. I've tried the following code on my `.zshrc` file:

```
lang_segment () {
    dir="$(dirname "$PWD")"
    if [[ $dir == *"Dev/python"* ]] ; then 
        echo -n "%{%F{yellow}%K{blue}'\uf81f' Python}"
    fi
    if [[ $dir == *"Dev/javascript"* ]] ; then
        echo -n "%{%F{black}%K{yellow}'\ue781' Javascript}"
    fi

}

POWERLEVEL9K_LEFT_PROMPT_ELEMENTS=(os_icon user dir custom_lang_segment vcs)
POWERLEVEL9K_CUSTOM_LANG_SEGMENT="lang_segment"
```

I'm using powerlevel9k theme. My idea is that when you cd into a folder inside the `dev/python` folder, a segment is shown with Python text, icon and color scheme, same for the `dev/javascript` folder or any language folder I use for that matter. As it is, nothing shows up. So my question is, is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue after some tinkering, the code looks like this:

```
prompt_lang_segment () {
    # Looks up the folder path + name
    dir="$( cd "$(dirname "$0")" ; pwd -P )"
    # Checks if it is the desired language/framework folder, in this case, python
    if [[ $dir == *"Dev/python"* ]] ; then 
        content="\uf81f Python%f"
        "$1_prompt_segment" "$0" "$2" "blue" "yellow" "$content" "#"
    fi
    if [[ $dir == *"Dev/js"* ]] ; then
        content="\ue781 Javascript%f"
        "$1_prompt_segment" "$0" "$2" "yellow" "black" "$content" "#"
    fi

...
}

# Added the lang_segment to the left prompt
POWERLEVEL9K_LEFT_PROMPT_ELEMENTS=(os_icon user dir lang_segment vcs)
```

I had to make a custom segment using prompt (`prompt_lang_segment` instead of just `lang_segment`) on the function and to work with it I had to change this:

```
echo -n "%{%F{black}%K{yellow}'\ue781' Javascript}"
```

into the default powerlevel9k command to show segments:

`"$1_prompt_segment" "$0" "$2" "yellow" "black" "$content" "#"`

So I added an if statement for each language/framework I had a folder for at this time and I also had to change the folder name javascript to js because it was showing both javascript and java segments.

This configuration works for the language/framework folder and all subfolders of it.
This is the end result:

[image]